# Scientist steals two insect-like aliens and raises them in his shed

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I've searched far and wide for this and, as I've got limited memory of it, I've no idea how to find the actual name of the film.

The premise of the film was of a scientist that was forced to retire from his job and, upon doing so, stole two insect-like creatures (aliens) that he kept in his personal shed outside his home.

As time went by, the creatures grew in size and one was blue, whilst the other was red. They gradually got bigger and multiplied, whilst gaining in intelligence and ended up building a "shrine" in sand to depict the scientist's face (i.e he was their God/creator).

After this, inevitably, everything goes wrong and the red and blue aliens end up having a war.

Anyone have an idea what this film is actually called?! I've run out of options other than asking here!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was the premiere episode of 1995's **The Outer Limits**, titled [Sandkings](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667945/).  From IMDB:

> When his research project is closed down, Simon Kress rescues a few of
>   its living subjects and transplants them to a recreation of their
>   native Martian environment in his barn. They grow and learn, but then
>   Kress makes an error with disastrous implications.

Actually based on a 1979 [novelette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandkings_%28novelette%29) by George R.R. Martin of **Game of Thrones** fame.